# Migration access to Oracle using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, ms-access, plsqldeveloper

I have to Migrate Access Office 365 database to Oracle 19c using sql developer 19.2 but when I open sql developer connection there is no option for access. Only all I can see for Oracle where I successfully connected to Oracle.
Can anyone help me how can I connect to access database and successfully migrate database to Oracle?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Regards,
Chandar

Comment: NO access tab beside Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be better to migrate Access database to SQL Server first (also called "upsizing"), and then to migrate the SQL Server database to Oracle.

Comment: Thank you for your time to reply.No the project doesnot allow that. It must migrate directly to access. There must be a way but the problem is that I don't know how to connect from SQL Developer 19.2 to Oracle 19c.